# will use request_pipeline increases performance in resty (lua)

Tags: http, lua, request-pipeline, resty

In lua resty https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http, I saw we can use request_pipeline for requests. I am wandering whether this will increase the performance. While after reading the source code, I found the request_pipeline method is also implemented with the regular send_request, and a loop is used to send each request one at a time.

Seems it cannot help to improve performance, if it is the case, why bothering to have this method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Someone answered on github https://github.com/pintsized/lua-resty-http/issues/130

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining
>
> Pipelining is intended to reduce latency when sending many requests.
>   It's not commonly used though as many intermediaries do not support it
>   well. It's part of the HTTP spec which is why its included.

Problem solved